# Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I got ADF that triggers Azure Functions by posting on HTTP url. After last support changes - function has been downgraded from v6 to v4 I got:

```
Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '404 : NotFound', 
message - 'The requested resource does not exist on the server. Please verify the request server and retry'
```

Could it be somehow connected with Storage Accounts changes or Networking?

EDIT:
Also, I have opened it in vscode, in bin directory I have something like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you try Azure Function activity in ADF?

Comment: No, I need quick fix. Currently I know also that function has been downgraded from v6 to v4.

Comment: This error happens when the Function name is not correct. check the function name in web activity URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got same error.

[image]

My Sample function name is `HttpTrigger1` and I got the above error when I gave it as `HttpTrigger2`.

Recheck the function name in the web activity URL.

[image]

Here, for sample demo I have used Get.

**Web activity executed successfully**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, but I'm sure that I have correct function name, in fact i get URL from "Get Function URL" so it should be fine. Also, previously it worked, before downgrade from v6 to v4. I can see that I have function runtime 3~

Comment: Check with any other sample function with different runtimes. If it results same, then the problem may be with the runtime.

Comment: I have opened azure functions in vscode and in bin directory I have 404, please see edited question. Could it be the cause? Can I just redeploy it or something?